# How to deploy to different environments with AWS SAM

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless, aws-sam

I have two questions about AWS SAM and deployments.

I’m reading through the docs and checking through examples like [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-well-architected-serverless-applications-approaching-application-lifecycle-management-part-2/) and I’m still not quite sure how to deploy to a `staging` and `production` environment separately with my SAM template. Is it as simple as deploying a new stack with a new name like `sam deploy —stack-name my-app-staging` and `sam deploy —stack-name my-app-production`?

In the following example, I have one question. If my SAM template contains a `Parameters` with the name `MyEnvironment` that has three possible values, how does the deploy know which value of the three to use when deploying the stack? Like how would I say to use the value `staging` or `production`? Is that something that will automatically be asked of me when I deploy or is it something I have to provide on the CLI?

[image]

Comment: It looks like for my second question, calling`—guided` would cause the user to be prompted to provide values for each parameter declared in the `Parameters` section. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification-template-anatomy.html) under `Parameters`.

Answer (score 45):

You can use [the `samconfig.toml` file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-config.html) in order to determine how the stack should be deployed to different environments.

For example:

```
version = 0.1

[qa.deploy.parameters]
stack_name = "my-qa-stack"
s3_bucket = "XXXXX-qa"
s3_prefix = "XXXXX/qa"
region = "eu-west-1"
capabilities = "CAPABILITY_IAM"
parameter_overrides = "Environment=qa"

[prod.deploy.parameters]
stack_name = "my-prod-stack"
s3_bucket = "XXXXX-prod"
s3_prefix = "XXXXX/prod"
region = "eu-west-1"
capabilities = "CAPABILITY_IAM"
parameter_overrides = "Environment=prod"
```

You can then pass the required config environment to the command:

```sh
sam deploy --config-env <qa|prod>
```

Comment: is there a way to use this variable in the template.yaml file? I want to use it in the function name; like this => `Resources:
  TestFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: <qa|prod>-function-name`

Comment: The `parameter_overrides` property sets the parameter values for the deployment of the stack. In the example above there is an `Environment` parameter. So if you define that parameter in your yaml stack, you can use `!Sub ${Environment}-function-name`.

Comment: amazing! worked pretty good